# Pandas treat the same DataFrame differently when read from excel or read from an API

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wrote a script before that read an excel file first and then manipulated the data frame, I replaced the read_excel part with an API and transposed it to look exactly as the excel file but now When I use the data directly from the API the rest of the script doesn't work properly but when I save the df to_excel and read_excel the script works fine!

**Working code:**

```
res = requests.post(url, headers = headers)
data = res.json()
data = data['body'][0]['data']
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.T

df.to_excel(path+name,index=False)
df = pd.read_excel(path+name)

df.columns=['ID','Name','Tel','1','2','3']
```

**Code with error:**

```
res = requests.post(url, headers = headers)
data = res.json()
data = data['body'][0]['data']
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.T

df.columns=['ID','Name','Tel','1','2','3']
```

PS: I've tried removing the index and converting the data types but nothing seems to work!

PPS: the error is traceback on not finding the 'Tel' column about 20 lines after this one, it can be fixed by adding the column to the previous line but the aggregation on another part still results in an empty data frame

EDIT:

Whenever I use a dictionary (or list) to create the data frame instead of or after read_excel the error is raised.

```
res = requests.post(url, headers = headers)
data = res.json()
data = data['body'][0]['data']
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.T

df.to_excel(path+name,index=False)
df = pd.read_excel(path+name)

dict1 = df.to_dict()
df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)

df.columns=['ID','Name','Tel','1','2','3']
```

this is the result of df.to_dict():

```
{0: 
{0: r'u7it'},
1: {0: 'تست'},
2: {0: None},
3: {0: 'کاملا موافقم'},
4: {0: 'موافقم'},
5: {0: 'کاملا موافقم'}
}
```

Comment: Your question is very difficult to answer without seeing (a) your data and (b) the actual error message you are getting. Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and post both (the data and the error message)

Comment: @piterbarg thanks for your advice, I can't provide a reprex here because I must include the API's authentication, I might be able to send it to a specific person instead, I should note that the error raises a traceback on not finding the 'Tel' column about 20 lines after this one, I can fix this by adding the column to the previous line but then the code doesn't do the aggregation on another part (the aggregation results in an empty data frame)

Comment: you do not need to provide the api. You can add the output of df.pay_history_by_interv.to_dict() suitably trimmed to highlight the problem you are having. (of course pls do make sure that you can reproduce the problem loading the df from the dict you provided)

Comment: @piterbarg the problem is raised whenever I change the df to dict and again back to dataframe I'll edit the post now thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but cannot format code in Comments. If I do this:

```
dict1 = {0: 
{0: r'u7it'},
1: {0: 'تست'},
2: {0: None},
3: {0: 'کاملا موافقم'},
4: {0: 'موافقم'},
5: {0: 'کاملا موافقم'}
}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
df.columns=['ID','Name','Tel','1','2','3']
```

I get no errors and df looks fine:

```
    ID      Name Tel    1      2             3
0   u7it    تست  None   کاملا موافقم    موافقم  کاملا موافقم
```

can you check your python version and pandas version? Mine are

```
!python -V

Python 3.8.8

!pip show pandas

Name: pandas
Version: 1.2.2
Summary: Powerful data structures for data analysis, time series, and statistics
Home-page: https://pandas.pydata.org
Author: None
Author-email: None
License: BSD
Location: c:\python38\lib\site-packages
Requires: numpy, python-dateutil, pytz
Required-by: seaborn, statsmodels
```

Comment: !python -V
Python 3.9.7
!pip show pandas
Name: pandas
Version: 1.3.3
Summary: Powerful data structures for data analysis, time series, and statistics
Home-page: https://pandas.pydata.org
Author: The Pandas Development Team
Author-email: pandas-dev@python.org
License: BSD-3-Clause
Location: c:\users\n.koochaki\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages
Requires: numpy, python-dateutil, pytz
Required-by: pathmagic, pyiotools, pysubtypes

Comment: Can I send you my script so u can take a look?